# MongoDB denormalization 'down' rather than embedding

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my first real foray into NoSQL and coming from a traditional RDBMS background it's hard to get my head around denormalizing data.  Most of the articles/books I've read it always boils down to [Embed or Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/).   However I was wondering how common a use case it is to bring elements of the parent into the child, without embedding.

As an example, consider I have the following 2 documents, which are a Tour an artist is doing and the individual gigs they are playing (this would be using references):

```
Tour:
  "artist": string,
  "genre": [string],
  "info": string
  "venue": {
    "name": string,
    "address": string
  }

Gig:
  "date": date,
  "tourId": string,
  "availableTickets": number
  "price": number
```

This data will come from numerous different sources and be written to MongoDB, for it then to be queried.  The most important factor for this application is read performance.

Initially I thought about embedding Gig within Tour but some Tours will have 1 or 2 Gigs, others will have 100+ so that would result in documents of wildly different sizes that could grow at different rates.

I then looked at relating (using above structures) but this made some queries difficult to answer as I was having to search both collections. Stuff like

- "Which gigs are Pink Floyd playing in August that have at least 4 tickets for less than 50"
- "Are there any daytime Jazz gigs in London next January"

I then thought about bringing some fields from Tour into Gig (e.g. Artist, Genre and Venue Name) so that queries like the above could be answered by just looking at the Gig collection.

This would obviously result in a LOT of redundant data. e.g. Prince is doing 400 gigs in a Tour, genre/artist etc would be duplicated. If he renames himself (again) I'd need to update all of these which would take time.

As the performance of Reads is definitely more important I'm thinking of going for this schema - does anyone have any experience/words of warning on this? Am I writing off embedding data prematurely? The difference in document size and fact that gigs will need accessed on their own makes me shy away from embedding but I'd like to know if the maintenance overhead of infrequent updates to Tours will be too much.

Comment: Regarding embedding Gig into Tour: Why do you think your documents will grow? Isn't the number of gigs pretty much known when the tour is created? Sure, there might be changes, but I doubt that you will create an empty tour and then add a new gigs to it every day.

Comment: Regarding redundancy: When using MongoDB you should always optimize for the most common use-case. Which use-case is more frequent: a) an artist gets renamed or b) a search is performed?

Comment: @Philipp - b) a search is performed (by a huge margin). Regarding your first comment - the number of Gigs isn't necessarily known at first. Often the record is created with a bare minimum of Gigs and they are added later.

Comment: Regarding the down vote for "primarily opinion-based" - please reword if it comes across this way. From what I'm reading all Mongo schema design is "art vs science" so will ultimately have some form of opinion but what I'm looking for is anyone with experience doing something similar to warn me if there's any fundamental issues with my approach.

Comment: Why are you trying to use mongodb for this, again?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The Tours + Gigs example is just a simplified generic example. My actual application has ~12 different 'Tour' types which can have varying fields, but share the same core/searchable fields. The same applies for Gigs, these will all have the same core fields but the rest of what's in them can differ wildly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think denormalizing information about parents into children is a schema design technique that is greatly underused, and it sounds like a good fit for your use case. A natural and common approach is to store parents with an array of children (or parents with an object of children, where the keys are variable and a priori unknown values - yikes!). This has a few drawbacks I can think of quickly:

- Difficult to read individual children
- Difficult to update logical groups of children, whether belonging to the same parent or to multiple parents
- Scalability problems if the number of children becomes very large or is updated frequently, causing document growth and movement on disk

Denormalizing the parent's data into the children solves the above problems with the obvious disadvantage of the duplication of the parent's data in all of its children and the resulting increased difficulty of updating the parent information. The idea of duplicating data scares people at first, but I think the cost is outweighed by the advantages in a read-heavy application. An occasional update of 400 documents in exchange for dodging multiple queries, client-side manipulation, or extra aggregation operations to fulfill normal reads is a victory.

There's also a hybrid approach as well, where your documents represent `Gig`s with core `Tour` information on each `Gig`, but also a reference to another collection of `Tour` documents that contain information infrequently needed when querying information about `Gig`s in a `Tour`.

Comment: I've actually just been playing with the hybrid approach you mentioned and it's looking good so far. Thanks for the answer - I haven't seen much about denormalizing parent -> child which made me wonder if I was missing something.